# Error installing OBS on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, obs-studio

I run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

After pressing the enter key to add the package and looking for updates, I get the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package obs-studio
```

I'm running 18.04.2 LTS on a Jetson Nano

Edit: Per @Nmath's request:

```
usr@usr-nano1:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.166  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.166  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease
Get:3 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease
Ign:3 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease
Get:4 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease
Ign:4 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.166  Release [574 B]
Get:6 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [1,999 B]
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.166  Release [574 B]                                  
Get:7 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,003 B]                                         
Get:6 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [1,999 B]                                 
Get:8 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,008 B]                                    
Get:7 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,003 B]                             
Get:8 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,008 B]                                    
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease                                    
Hit:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
usr@usr-nano1:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
usr@usr-nano1:~$ more /etc/apt/sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multive
rse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: the package `obs-studio` is available in `universe` repositories.  You do not need to add a non-Ubuntu repository to install this software.  (Adding a repo should not be taken lightly)  You only need to enable `universe` and run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install obs-studio`.

Comment: In general your problem means that the PPA provider has not provided a package called `obs-studio` that matches your Ubuntu version.

Comment: @Nmath `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources` with the resulting same error when running `sudo apt install obs-studio`